# Recorrer matriz con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo este array de arrays , para mostrar un valor uso:

```
alert(var_dump(objView.ArrayStock[1][0].STOCK_REAL));

ArrayStock:[[{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}, {BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}],…]
0:[{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}, {BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}]
    0:{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}
    1:{BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}
1:[{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}, {BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}]
    0:{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}
    1:{BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}
2:[{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}, {BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}]
    0:{BODEGA: "01", STOCK_REAL: "17.00"}
    1:{BODEGA: "03", STOCK_REAL: "9.00"}
```

Actualmente para arrays normales uso:

```
$.each(objView.ArrayStock, function (indice, elemento) {
alert(indice + " : " + elemento.STOCK_REAL);/* no se como recorrerlo cuando es un array de arrays*/
});
```

¿De que forma lo tendría que recorrer parar mostrar solo el "STOCK_REAL" de los 3 arrays?, se me imagina que tengo que usar dos each o existirá una forma mas simple de recorrerlo.

Esto es lo que llevo , consigo mostrar solo un elemento :

```
$.each(objView.ArrayStock, function (indice, elemento) {
    alert(indice + " : " + elemento[indice]);

    each(elemento,function(indice2, elemento2) {
      alert(indice + " : " + elemento2[indice2].STOCK_REAL);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recorrer una **matriz**, solo hay que agregar otro ciclo, un ciclo recorre vertical y otro horizontal, cuando es solo un ciclo se hace de manera horizontal

Una matriz es un **arreglo** el cual en cada indice tiene otro **arreglo**, lo que tu haces actualmente es recorrer solo un arreglo, pero como en este arreglo en los indices contienes otros arreglo, hay que recorrer este segundo arreglo con otro ciclo.

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu matriz:

```js
var objView = {ArrayStock: [
  [{
    BODEGA: "01",
    STOCK_REAL: "17.00"
  }, {
    BODEGA: "03",
    STOCK_REAL: "9.00"
  }],
  [{
    BODEGA: "01",
    STOCK_REAL: "17.00"
  }, {
    BODEGA: "03",
    STOCK_REAL: "9.00"
  }],
  [{
    BODEGA: "01",
    STOCK_REAL: "17.00"
  }, {
    BODEGA: "03",
    STOCK_REAL: "9.00"
  }]
]}

$.each(objView.ArrayStock, function(indice, elemento) {
  $.each(elemento, function(indice2, elemento2) {
    console.log(indice + " : " + elemento2.STOCK_REAL);
    /* no se como recorrerlo cuando es un array de arrays*/
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Estoy siguiendo los pasos como me mencionas pero aun no logro recorrer el arreglo , si edito la pregunta me puedes ayudar? gracias

Comment: Claro, te marca algún error? en consola?

Comment: No ningun error en consola se me imagina que tengo algo malo en la logica, de los each, no logro llegar al stock_real de los arrays

Comment: revisa los parámetros de la función, en el primer `.each()` tengo `indice `y` elemento` en el segundo `.each()` tengo `indice2` y `elemento2`.

Comment: edite la pregunta estimado, gracias, la variable objView es la que viene por json

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar del edit que hicistes tienes esto mal `elemento2[indice2].STOCK_REAL`,  elemento2  ya no es un arreglo así que cámbialo y déjalo de esta forma: `elemento2.STOCK_REAL`  o bien solo quita el `2` de `elemento2`

Comment: gracias estimado me sirvió saludos !

Answer (score 0):

aqui otro ejemplo con recursividad

```
var data = [
  [{
    BODEGA: "01",
    STOCK_REAL: "17.00"
  }, {
    BODEGA: "03",
    STOCK_REAL: "9.00"
  }],
  [{
    BODEGA: "01",
    STOCK_REAL: "17.00"
  }, {
    BODEGA: "03",
    STOCK_REAL: "9.00"
  }],
  [{
    BODEGA: "01",
    STOCK_REAL: "17.00"
  }, {
    BODEGA: "03",
    STOCK_REAL: "9.00"
  }]
]
recorrerBodegas(data);
function recorrerBodegas(data){
  for (detalle in data){

   if(Array.isArray(data[detalle])){
    recorrerBodegas(data[detalle]);
   }else{
        console.log("para el detalle " + detalle + " el resultado de BODEGA:"+ data[detalle].BODEGA);
        console.log("para el detalle " + detalle + " el resultado de STOCK_REAL:"+ data[detalle].STOCK_REAL);
   }
  }
}
```

el ejemplo en https://jsfiddle.net/e1rov91m/